# Interpretation of data

Tags: rf, radiation, em

I hope this question meets the standards of this platform, if not please inform me of how I can improve it.

I was trying to design an antenna and I have done so. I am planning on using this antenna in an RFID application inside a metal container measuring in at 2.89m by 1.89m by 5.2m (WxHxD). Whereby this antenna designed is the RFID reader's antenna and is mounted inside the metal container as shown in the picture. This reader's antenna will detect RFID tags which are placed on pallets and inserted in the container.

My problem statement:

I am investigating the EM-field created from this antenna in the container using CST software. I want to monitor how this antenna behaves in this environment. My antenna measures in at 8cm by 8cm with a gain of 2.37dBi and an axial ratio of 1.5 at the resonant frequency of 915MHz. I have performed the simulation and I applied an E-field probe in the container and I got the following graph. The probe location is shown as a green arrow in the picture. Can someone help me in interpreting these results in the graph?

At 915MHz the E-field measures at 22.3dB as shown in the graph.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I see at least two takeaways from your graph: as expected there are a lot of standing waves inside the metal enclosure, what explains the up/down behavior of the frequency response every tenths of MHz; the antenna seems reasonably tuned for 915MHz, as the overall envelope of the curve has a peak around there.

Comment: Is the value of 22dB good or bad. I haven't got any practical experience with this so I won't know if that value is good or bad in reality.

Comment: Since the output of the probe is an absolute value of the electric field in volts/meter, its magnitude only has meaning if you know the input power required to achieve that value.  Then you can compare those values to other antennas to determine how good your design is..

Comment: @Barry the input power was 2W. How would I then know if the results are acceptable?